# Filling missing values with the value above

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with some missing values. I need to update one `'nan'` value with the last value not `'nan'` in a row.

Example:

```
    nome
0   ESTAMPA DIGITAL 1
1   nan
2   nan
3   nan
4   nan
5   ESTAMPA DIGITAL 2
6   nan
7   nan
8   nan
9   nan
```

need to produce something like this:

```
    nome
0   ESTAMPA DIGITAL 1
1   ESTAMPA DIGITAL 1
2   ESTAMPA DIGITAL 1
3   ESTAMPA DIGITAL 1
4   ESTAMPA DIGITAL 1
5   ESTAMPA DIGITAL 2
6   ESTAMPA DIGITAL 2
7   ESTAMPA DIGITAL 2
8   ESTAMPA DIGITAL 2
9   ESTAMPA DIGITAL 2
```

current code is:

```py
for index, row in df_produtos.iterrows():
    is_null = pd.isnull(row['nome'])
    if is_null == False:
        nome = row['nome']
        print(nome)
    elif is_null == True:
        row['nome'] = nome
```

But it's not working. Somebody can help please?
PS: the `print(nome)` is printing only `"valid"` values that is not `'nan'`. But it's not setting the new value.

Comment: use fill foward?

Comment: just learning pandas, do not know this feature yet... I will try! Thanks Dani!

Comment: @DaniMesejo it worked perfectly!! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`.ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) to forward fill the `NaN` values, as follows:

```
df_produtos['nome'] = df_produtos['nome'].ffill()
```

Comment: it worked perfectly!! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: done! Thank you!